# How do I watch for VidoeView onStop() action?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I would like to trigger an event when my VideoView is done playing?  How woudl I do this? can you show me an example or direct my to some resources?

Im thinking something like this.

```
if(!videoView.isplaying()){
//trigger event
}

or

public void onStop(){

//trigger event 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know when play has completed, you would use [VideoView.setOnCompletionListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29).

```
myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){

    @Override 
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){

       // do on completion stuff.
    }
});
```

If you want to detect error cases, you would use VideoView.setOnErrorListener() instead.